# Is Plantera in console Terraria?

Tags: terraria-console

Is Plantera actually in the console version of terraria? I have defeated all 3 mechanical bosses and Ocram (just in case), with the same character dealing the killing blow, the message does appear on the first win. Me and 3 others have been digging for the underground jungle for 2 weeks and have filled our entire map for the underground jungle and have yet to find a single bulb, plus on another note I don't believe chlorophyte ore can grow before Plantera has been defeated because I left some to grow for 10 hours checked (none), saved and exited, reloaded and still none. I would really appreciate to know wether or not I should keep looking or wait for an update.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera#History), **yes**, Plantera is in the console version of Terraria as of version 1.2.

It's possible that you're encountering a bug, though. Sometimes, the bulbs to spawn Plantera will not spawn at all, especially in the console version.

Comment: I would recommend adding something to this about the fact that, apparently there are known issues with Plantera and Chlorophyte spawning, as indicated in numerous posts on this forum about the 1.2 console update: http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/regarding-the-1-2-console-update-issues.140593/

Comment: Ok, thank you for the feedback I was just wondering because we had tries 2 different maps with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can spawn and defeat Plantera on the console edition. If you have lots of bushes and plants like this:

[image: Bush]

Then destroy them to give more room for the bulb to spawn, the more ground there is, the more chance the bulb has of spawning. It is just a random chance, you'll just have to wait and keep checking.

Also chlorophyte doesn't grow before you beat Plantera.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is spawnable. Sencibly in the jungle biome find an odd looking plant bulb(not maneater or dragonfly snatcher) smash it and it SHOULD come.